# gz log file won't run

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run diagnostics on a Gazebo log file that won't play back using `gazebo -p state.log`. I get the error:

> [FATAL] [1479922107.060392505]: A ROS
> node for Gazebo has not been
> initialized, unable to load plugin.
> Load the Gazebo system plugin
> 'libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so' in the
> gazebo_ros package) [Err]
> [Plugin.hh:165] Failed to load plugin
> libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so:
> libGpuRayPlugin.so: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory

Running `dpkg -S libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so` gives me:

> ros-indigo-gazebo7-plugins: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so

and  `dpkg -S libGpuRayPlugin.so` gives me:

> gazebo7-plugin-base: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-7/plugins/libGpuRayPlugin.so

I see that its suggested to run `gz log -i -f state.log` in order to confirm that the log file is valid. I get:

> Log Version:    1.0
> Gazebo Version: 7.4.0
> Random Seed:    1989963430
> Size:           192.607 MB
> Encoding:       zlib

It was also suggested that I run the command `tail -1 state.log` and check to see if that outputs
`</gazebo>` which it does.

Now I'm out of ideas on what to try next.

**System info:**
Gazebo 7
ROS Indigo
Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14903/gz-log-file-won%27t-run/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2922/shoemakerlevy9/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Running the command as a super user fixed the issue

```
sudo gazebo -p state.log --verbose
```

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2922/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 1 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0